# Finding map between metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

I am a bit confused when it comes to finding the coordinate maps that can take me from one metric to another.

Consider a metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ and $h_{ab}$. Generally, we have the relation
\begin{equation}
h_{ab}= \partial_a x^\mu \partial_b x^\nu g_{\mu \nu}.
\end{equation}
But I find this formula difficult to apply when $\{a,b\} \neq \{ \mu,\nu \}$, because how would I know the embedding $x^\mu(x^a)$, i.e. what coordinates $x^\mu$ that depends on $x^a$?

There must be a simple algorithm that can find the map between two arbitrary metrics, although i practice it might be tedious to solve for?

Say that I have some metric
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu = d\sigma^2 - \cosh^2 \sigma dt^2 + \sinh^2 \sigma d\theta^2
\end{equation}
and another metric
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = h_{ab} dx^a dx^b = d\chi^2 +\sinh^2 \chi \left(-d \tau^2 + \cosh^2 \tau d\theta^2 \right).
\end{equation}

How would I find the transformation(s) that takes me from one metric to another? Since the coordinates are different I don't in principle know if $\chi$ and $\tau$ both depend on both $t$ and $\sigma$?

Do I assume that they potentially do and solve two sets of partial differential equations? I.e. solve

\begin{equation}
h_{\tau \tau} = g_{\sigma \sigma} (\partial_\tau \sigma(\chi, \tau))^2 + g_{tt} (\partial_\tau t(\chi, \tau))^2, \quad
h_{\chi \chi}= g_{\sigma \sigma}(\partial_\chi \sigma(\chi, \tau))^2 + g_{tt} (\partial_{\chi} t(\chi, \tau))^2.
\end{equation}
simultaneously?

Comment: If you are given both metrics, then there isn't much use in deducing the mapping between them. But assuming that you want to find it for some reason, then your last expressions are (almost) correct. You just need to also add the $g_{\theta \theta} \left (\partial _{a} \theta \right) \left( \partial _{b} \theta \right )$ contribution to each expression, as well as an expression for $h_{\theta \theta}$. Generally, you should always start by assuming any coordinate in one system is a function of all coordinates in another system and deduce any simplifications later on.